# Проверка выходных данных

Tags: c

В конце, как я понял программа смотрит, делится ли Z на предыдущий элемент массива, если не делится то выводится 0. Не могу понять как сделать так чтобы вместо 0 выводился текст по типу: "Элементы не являются членами геометрической прогрессии". Если делится то выводится Z, если нет, то текст.
Листинг:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

 
int main(void)
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int a[10];
    int n;
 
    printf("N: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
 
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i){
        printf("a[%i] : ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
 
    float z=(float)a[1]/(float)a[0];
    for (i=1; i<n; ++i) {
        if (z!=(float)a[i]/(float)a[i-1]) {
            z=0;
        }
    }
    printf("%f\n: ",z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Приведите вашу попытку решить задачу.

Comment: Попробуйте применить конструкцию `if (z ...) printf("..."); else printf("...");`

Answer (score 1):

Это

```
float z=(float)a[1]/(float)a[0];
for (i=1; i<n; ++i) {
    if (z!=(float)a[i]/(float)a[i-1]) {
        z=0;
    }
}
```

очень плохая идея — сравнивать числа с плавающей точкой на равенство. Куда лучше сравнивать целочисленные значения, которые сравниваются *точно*:

```
for (i=1; i<n; ++i) {
    if (a[1]*a[i-1] != a[0]*a[i]) 
    {
        printf("Это не геометрическая прогрессия\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```